# Opensource Java Projects with JUnit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, open-source, junit4

I am currently working on developing a mutation testing tool and I need to find an Open Source Java project which has a relatively good amount of JUnit Tests. The idea is that I'll be using the opensource system and its TestSuite so as to perform a case study on my mutation testing tool. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have written a mutation testing tool.

I recommend that you make sure your mutation tester detects the unnecessary code in [Bob Martin's Bowling Scorer](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm) game as described [here](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/extremeprogramming/conversations/topics/32277).  It's not much code so it's a quick check.